# Why is the argument position of split and join in clojure.string mixed up?

Tags: string, clojure

I wanted to do this:

```lisp
(-> string
    (str/split "\s")
    (modification-1)
    (modification-2)
    …
    (modification-n
    (str/join "\n"))
```

But no, split takes `[s regex]` and join takes `[seperator coll]`.

Is there any apparent reason for this madness (read: What is the design decision behind this)?

Comment: What is wrong with ? (join "\n" (split string "\s"))

Comment: I left out a few modification functions in between. Adding them for clarity.

Comment: Why? `clojure.string.join` is consistent with other functions that take collections. `(map f col) (filter f col)`

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Well, Strings are considered sequences in Clojure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of Clojure 1.5, you can also use one of the new threading macros.

> clojure.core/as->
>
> ([expr name & forms])
>
> Macro
>
> Binds name to expr, evaluates the first form in the lexical context
>     of that binding, then binds name to that result, repeating for each
>     successive form, returning the result of the last form.

It's quite a new construct, so not sure how to use idiomatically yet, but I guess something like this would do:

```
(as-> "test test test" s
    (str/split s #" ")
    (modification-1 s)
    (modification-2 s)
    ...
    (modification-n s)
    (str/join "\n" s))
```

**Edit**

As for why the argument position is different, I'm in no place to say, but I think Arthur's suggestion makes sense:

- Some functions clearly operate on collections (`map`, `reduce`, etc). These tend to consistently take the collection as the last argument, which means they work well with `->>`
- Some functions don't operate on collections and tend to take the most important argument (*is that a thing?*) as the first argument. For example, when using `/` we expect the numerator to come first. These functions work best with `->`

The thing is - some functions are ambiguous. They might take a collection and produce a single value, or take a single value and produce a collection. `string\split` is one example (disregarding for the moment that additional confusion that a string could be thought of as both a single value *or* a collection). Concatenation/reducing operations will also do it - they will mess up your pipeline!

Consider, for instance:

```
(->> (range 1 5)
     (map inc)
     (reduce +)
     ;; at this point we have a single value and might want to...
     (- 4)
     (/ 2))
     ;; but we're threading in the last position
     ;; and unless we're very careful, we'll misread this arithmetic
```

In those cases, I think something like `as->` is really helpful.

I think in general the guideline to use `->>` when operating on collections and `->` otherwise is sound - and it's just in these borderline/ambiguous cases, `as->` can make the code a little neater, a little clearer.

Comment: Love this new macro. There was a library that could do this, great to see it arriving in `core`.

Comment: This is much better than the old way, and makes the code much easier to read because I don't have to imagine the missing argument when I read it.

Comment: Carrying a torch for [tag:forth], I love the threading macro, but was secretly hoping for a threaded equivalents of `swap`, `roll`, and `dup` to manipulate argument order. Ah well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use partial function to fix the separator argument for str/join.

```
(-> string
  (str/split #"\s")
  (modification-1)
  (modification-2)
  ;;
  (modification-n)
  ((partial str/join "\n")))
```

Comment: i suppose that would put the string into the partial form. surround it with brackets?

Comment: you can also do ...(modification-n) (->> (str/join "\n")))

Comment: Are you sure it will work? Seems to me that the result of modification-n will be threaded before str/join in the partial.

Answer (score 2):

I also run into this sort of (minor) threading headache fairly regularly.

```
(-> string
    (str/split "\s")
    (modification-1)
    (modification-2)
    …
    (modification-n
    (#(str/join "\n" %)))
```

and often create an anonymous function to make the ordering match. My guess as to why is that some functions where intended to be used with thread first `->`, some for thread last `->>` and for some threading was not a design goal, though this is just a guess.

Comment: Accepted this because it works for every function and tries to find an answer to the question.

Comment: I guess the second arrow should be `->>`, though.

Comment: Daniel Neal's answer is much better

Comment: That is true, but it doesn’t answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with threading your threaded expression through another threading macro, like this:

```
(-> string
    (str/split "\s")
    modification-1
    modification-2
    modification-n
    (->> (str/join "\n")))
```